# Export list of API Paths from OpenAPI spec using swagger ui

Tags: swagger-ui

I have a bunch of APIs that are documented as OpenAPI v3 specs.

Eg: foo.yaml, bar.yaml and baz.yaml

I also have a Web server that displays the specs in the [swagger ui](https://petstore.swagger.io/), so all my swagger models are easily consumable by devs, designers and so on.

My question: is there an easy way, using the javascript console, to give me a list of the resource paths?

I've had a quick look around the swagger ui source code but couldn't find anything useful, other than the SwaggerUIBundle object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API definition is accessible via `ui.specSelectors.specJson()`. The value is an Immutable.js [`Map`](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map).

You can use the following code to list all the paths:

```js
let paths = ui.specSelectors.specJson().get("paths")
paths.mapKeys(key => console.log(key))
```